# Python Pandas - exporting a large dataframe to excel worksheet

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been trying to export a large data frame to a specific worksheet in excel, but have been getting an error: "TypeError: Objects of type 'datetime.time' can not be converted to a COM VARIANT"

I have tried to do some research, but cant seem to find out what the problem is. This is the code I am trying to use:

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book('filename.xlsx')
sht = wb.sheets['FNC']
data = wb.sheets['Data']
smdata = wb.sheets['SM Data']

Main_Data = df_ALL

data.range('data2').value = Main_Data
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also see this error

You could convert all your `datetime.time` objects into strings

```
import datetime
df_temp = df.applymap(lambda x: str(x) if isinstance(x, datetimetime) else x)

data.range('data2').value = df_temp
```

## or

Since you're saying you have a large dataframe you could decide which columns contain the time object and just replace those:

```
df[columns_to_replace] = df[columns_to_replace].applymap(lambda x: str(x) if isinstance(x, datetimetime) else x)

data.range('data2').value = df
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you are trying to put data of type that is not time to a cell/column in the Excel file that is formatted that way. I suggest either starting without any particular format of Excel columns and then change their format.

For these reasons I am wondering if programmatic Excel spreadsheet manipulation is a must. I would export the data to csv and loaded it in bulk which should be much faster for larger portions of data (albeit potentially partially manual).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. 
There is no formatting for the worksheet Data. Infact, i have just tried to create a new worksheet with a different name and still get the same problem. Any solution to this @sophros?

Thanks